# Add UILabel in UITableViewCell with storyboard using Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I am watching wwdc2013 session video: 406-Taking Control of Auto Layout in Xcode 5. I found out the UILabel is added into the UITableViewCell not in the cell's contentView, I am trying to replicate the same myself. I tried drag the UILabel onto the cell, it's automatically add as a subview of cell's contentView. How did they do that?

Comment: what exactly you can't do? I'm downloading the movie now to see what exactly you talk about, but generally CellViews aren't making problems they're quietly nice behaviour :) heheheh

Comment: Ok, i can't found link for that 406 movie if you can send link I'm sure i can help you with that thanks